# C# Task run only if time is right - at a certain time

Tags: c#, sql, rest, api, task

Okay, so i need to build a c# task that will only run at a certian time, the time will come from a SQL database, and it can be more then 1 time a day.

For an example, the c# task need to run at 6:00, 13:00, 15:00 and 19:00. and at the meanwhile time it will sleep.

I was thinking to just do Task.delay(60000) and check then run on a loop of times and check if DateTime.Now < time.

But that seems like it will overload my computer wouldn't it?
I cant use windows manager because my task is on a windows service doing other tasks.

What is the best possible way of doing this such of work?

P.S : the task job is to go for an api and get info into a Database.

Thanks a lot for helping!

Comment: When you put words in double quotes, that isn't quoting what someone is saying, then it means that you are using this word however it's not exactly what you mean. So the phrase 'at the "mean" time' is quite confusing. But it seems to me you meant to write **meantime** which is a synonym for **meanwhile**.

Comment: Yes, you are right. i am sorry, my bad.

Comment: @JPatrik you are asking for SQL Server Agent, a timer or a Task Scheduler job, not Task. For long running tasks the options are SQL Server Agent and Task Scheduler. Tasks represent *one* asynchronous execution.

Comment: @JPatrik for long-running schedules you can add Hangfire or Quartz.NET to your service. Btw you *can* use Task Manager and SQL Server Agent for this - you can use them to send a command to the service

Comment: @JPatrik another option is to *poll* the database periodically using a timer and check for items that need processing now. Reading from the database eg once per minute should be very cheap, especially if the time field is indexed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Task scheduler](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/using-the-task-scheduler) Windows

> The Task Scheduler can be used to execute tasks such as starting an
>   application, sending an email message, or showing a message box. Tasks
>   can be scheduled to execute:
>
> At a specific time.
>
> At a specific time on a daily schedule.

You can try [this](https://github.com/dahall/taskscheduler) to create a task dynamically for each day,

```
   using System;
   using Microsoft.Win32.TaskScheduler;
   static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      // Get the service on the local machine
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Create a trigger that will fire the task at this time every other day
         td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 2 });

         // Create an action that will launch your application whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("my_application.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);

         // Remove the task we just created
         ts.RootFolder.DeleteTask("Test");
      }
   }
```

You write your `my_application.exe` for connection API et pull to database. Next, config the task created to call your application.

[Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) is also an option with a richer API to create a task and save it to database. But I think `Windows Scheduled` tasks might give you all you need.

Comment: I've already explained that my c# task is ruining in a windows service that does a lot of other things. i cant use Task scheduler. the other problem even if i wanted to use windows scheduler is that my times come back my SQL DATABASE , so i cant know what time it is.

Comment: Create a proper application and called by scheduler

Comment: How can i use a scheduler if i need to give it X time, my time can change from day to day. and i want it to be fully automatic.

Comment: @JPatrik you can use Task Manager or better yet, SQL Server Agent to send a command to the service. As for `my times come back my SQL DATABASE` sounds like you tried to implement your own Quartz.NET or Hangfire

Comment: This is sound good because it does do what i need. but isn't it easier to just create a task and check for the time? in here i would need to create 3 jobs each day. if i need to delete one its a pain to get get the right one. if i have an error its a pain to deal with it. what do you think?

Comment: It's up to you. I give just the idea. One idea: in application c#, after executing an action at 6:00, you update the time of the task for 12:00.

Answer (score 2):

You should take a look at Quartz .NET:

https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/

If I understand you correctly, the times when it needs to run will be fetched from a SQL database, so your windows service should probably check every once in a while, whether the schedule has been updated and re-schedule in the application if relevant.

Another project which is really nice is Hangfire:

https://www.hangfire.io/

Either one would probably allow you to do what you need.

Here's an example of what you could do (in Hangfire):

```
// Get database times. For simplicity I'll assume that you
// just get a list of dates. Assume they're stored in in UTC
List<DateTime> times = this.database.GetSchedule();

// Loop the times and schedule jobs
foreach(var time in times) 
{
   var timeUntilJob = time - DateTime.UtcNow;
   var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => YourMethodToDoWork(), timeUntilJob);

   // You will need to somehow store the job ids, in case you want to 
   // cancel an execution scheduled for a later time (e.g. if you
   // need to update it if the database-stored schedule changes).
   // You could then invoke BackgroundJob.Delete(jobId)
 }
```

Hangfire can e.g. store the scheduled invocations in a SQL Server database (or Redis or MongoDb, etc). It creates records containing the assembly, the method and the arguments to invoke at the scheduled time.
This means that even if your service breaks down, you won't lose executions of your task.

You could just create a timer that ticks every X hours and deletes the current schedule, and updates with the current values in the database. But how you want to do that is of course up to your specific case.

Comment: Please don't link to libraries. Show how it should be done and link only if supporting what's already in your answer.

Comment: Ok, I figured the poster probably just needed a pointer to a library that allowed him/her to implement what he needed. I will update the post with an example.