# C# - Generate one time task in Windows Task Planner

Tags: c#, .net

I am looking for a method in C# and .NET Framework 4.7 to create a one-time job in Windows Task Planner. I have found several APIs, such as ASquare.WindowsTaskScheduler or dahall's Task Scheduler, but they can only create recurring tasks.

For background, I want the program to run once a day and create several tasks that change daily. These need to be in the Windows Task Scheduler so they can be easily edited should changes occur during the day.

I hope you can help me to find a solution :)

Best regards!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# Task run only if time is right - at a certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609097/c-sharp-task-run-only-if-time-is-right-at-a-certain-time) and [Creating Scheduled Tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67698658/c-sharp-generate-one-time-task-in-windows-task-planner) and [Creating a custom and reliable task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52663775/creating-a-custom-and-reliable-task-scheduler)

Comment: @OlivierRogier Unfortunately not, they are all about daily triggers. The task should run only once and never again.

Comment: @.saltemohn Just set the trigger to one time: https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler/wiki/TriggerSamples. Example: `wintask.Triggers.Add(new TimeTrigger(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)));`